# What is the difference between rdl and rdlc in ssrs reports?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

What is the difference between RDL and RDLC for SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) reports?

I am working on SSRS reports for SQL Server 2014 on behalf of RDL.  When I try to create RDL reports in SSRS it is storing in RDLC.  Can you tell me the procedure to produce RDL reports please?

Comment: You could've [googled](https://www.google.nl/search?q=what%27s+the+difference+between+ssrs+RDL+and+RDLC) that yourself.

Answer (score 4):

RDL files are report files that are designed to be used with SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), and stored in the Report Server and executed from there. You can use a Report Viewer control in your projects to access these reports.

RDLC files are 'local reports' that are created in Visual Studio, retained locally and not stored on an SSRS server. They can also be used with the Report Viewer control, but don't need SQL Server Reporting Services to execute.

RDL files and RDLC files may have similar XML schemas but are not necessarily the same, depending on the versions of SQL Server and Visual Studio you are working with.

To create RDL files when you are using SQL Server 2014 as in your situation, you need to user SQL Server Data Tools and create a New Project. From the Business Intelligence templates, choose a 'Reporting Services' project, and from there you can create your reports.

I think the problem you're getting is you're making a Visual Studio project (like a C# project) and creating a new item of type Report. This would be a local report (RDLC) and not the kind you are after when using SSRS.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply for my query. Yes I had worked through c# i am trying to work report viewer i am not getting.                                                                                                                            Can you provide any document or links or videos about how to use the SSRS to my mail ID: tonuneeraj@gmail.com so that i can  work on my PC

Comment: thank you very much.if i have any doubts i will contact you again.

Answer (score 0):

RDL files are created by the SQL Server 2005 version of Report Designer. RDLC files are created by the Visual Studio 2008 version of Report Designer. RDL and RDLC formats have the same XML schema. ... By manually binding data, RDL files can be used in the ReportViewer control.